# What does AWS ECS Task size (cpu & memory) mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, memory, cpu, amazon-ecs

I'm confused about how my **ECS Task** can run a **docker image that is 1.5GB** in size (value I see in ECR) with the **ECS Task** size being **0.5GB**?

Any help on clarification on how Task size cpu & memory are related to the actual execution of the app would be helpful!

Comment: The docker image just needs to fit onto disk, not memory. You are confusing disk space and RAM.

Comment: @MarkB I think it's legitimate confusion - doesn't the container need to be launched into memory? Or are you saying that only part of the container image is moved from disk to be held in RAM? What is an image if not an executable that is executed? Maybe that's it - just like any other program, an image only makes use of RAM resources / arrays, and does not live in RAM.

Comment: @jtlz2 a docker image contains a file system. It's like a copy of a hard disk. Only one file in the image is executed (loaded into memory), by docker, and that is the file you specify as the entrypoint for the image. The entrypoint may load other files into memory, but that is entirely dependent on what you are doing in your containerized application.

Comment: Thank you, got it, perfect! Then the OP was indeed as confused :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no relation at all between the size of the image and the amount of resources (cpu and memory) you assign to a task. You could instantiate a multiple GB container image with a tiny task size (like 0.5GB of memory) if all your container process does is very little and doesn't need a huge amount of memory/cpu. Conversely, you may need a gigantic task size to run a process off of a container whose originating image is just a few MB. No correlation at all.

Comment: Interesting! And image size is not charged for (except, presumably, by ECR?)?

Comment: Correct. But with nuances: if you use ECS/EC2 you pay for EBS disk space that will store your images on the EC2 instances. If you use ECS/Fargate [20GB is included in the Fargate price with the ability to extend it to up to 200GB (you pay for the additional capacity you configure)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation of the status quo!